# How to solve error in Configuration.cs in code first migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I was setting up code first migration for model changes from `Package Manager Console` which creates `seed`method in ***`Configuration.cs`***. i placed my code in `Seed` method and it shows error at **context.Movies.AddorUpdate(-----**

it says
:

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate(System.Data.Entity.IDbSet,
>   params TEntity[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying
>   the type arguments explicitly.

```
protected override void Seed(MvcMovie.Models.MovieDbContext context)
{ 
    context.Movies.AddOrUpdate(
    i => i.Title,
        new Movie
        {
            Title = "When Harry Met Sally",
            ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("1989-1-11"),
            Genre = "Romantic Comedy",
            Price = 7.99M
        },

        new Movie
        {
            Title = "Ghostbusters ",
            ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("1984-3-13"),
            Genre = "Comedy",
            Price = 8.99M
        },

        new Movie
        {
            Title = "Ghostbusters 2",
            ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("1986-2-23"),
            Genre = "Comedy",
            Price = 9.99M
        }
    );
}
```

Movie.cs

```
namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Title 
        {
            get;
            set; 
        }

        [Display(Name="ReleaseDate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate 
        {
            get;
            set; 
        }
        public string Genre 
        { 
            get;
            set;
        }
        public decimal Price 
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }
   public class MovieDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more code, like your MovieDbContext class, but adding context.Movies.AddOrUpdate<Movie> Might solve the issue.

Comment: tried. Not working @swestner

Comment: What's the generic typeparam for Movies DbSet{T}? You could paste the code for MovieDbContext class.

Comment: Please add your Movie class as well as your DbContext and configuration class if applicable

Comment: Judging by the error message, it seems like you're calling the wrong overload of `AddOrUpdate`. What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: Was it the same error? also, could you post could you post your MovieDbContext?

Comment: I have added Movie.cs in question

Comment: @DinavAhire, Entity Framework 5 doesn't contain the `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions` type. Please check where did it come from.

Comment: it is framework 6. i already edited my comment

Comment: I notice you're using the fully qualified namespace in `Seed(MvcMovie.Models.MovieDbContext context)`... It's possible you need to reference the `new Movie` the same way if you're not `using` that namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing is likely due to you having multiple classes called `Movie`. I suggest you take a look at your namespaces and `using` statements to tidy this up. But, if you cannot change them, specify the type explicitly using the full namespace (I'm guessing which namespace to use here, you may need the "other" one!):

```
context.Movies.AddOrUpdate(
    i => i.Title,
    new MvcMovie.Models.Movie
      //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Note the full namespace here
    {
        Title = "When Harry Met Sally",
        ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("1989-1-11"),
        Genre = "Romantic Comedy",
        Price = 7.99M
    },
    //Snip rest of code
);
```